# How to input attribute data quickly in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

In ArcMap I select a polygon (in edit mode) and press the number keys from 0 to 9 on the keyboard an appropriate value recorded in the attribute table of selected polygons in a specified field.

Is it possible to set hotkeys in ArcMap for this case?

I have a layer "Build" with the field "Level_final" (long integer). I editing process I input value from 0 to 9 and for the convenience and speed I need "hot keys" that would be implemented next step: when typed on the keyboard any keys from 0 to 9 the same value prescribed in the field "Level_final". I can do it in window with feature attributes, but it is slower. I have a tool that performs that function for MapInfo and it is made in the form of hot keys. But since I work more in the ArcMap and wont have such "hotkeys" in ArcMap

I know all about attribute window but, believe me, it is still slow when you need manual (without the automatic calculated) input data from 0 to 9 to 10,000 polygons per day! I wrote that for MapInfo exists this functionality as a hotkeys and it works very quickly and efficiently! So I want to realize this functionality for ArcMap!

Comment: Can you explain what the 0-9 values to relate to? If they are a basic classification system (When column A = "Dog", Column B = 9), I would recommend a python If/else statement. I can post an example in the answers if that applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Arcobjects Add-in that allows you to attribute features with hotkeys. It can be customized by editing an XML file. I have not tested it. https://geoapplications.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/speedy-attribute-editing-with-a-custom-arcmap-add-in/

the download link is bad

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is almost what I need, but I have not found a script for Python or links to files Arcobjects Add-in? Could you provide me with this information?

Answer (score 1):

From the edit toolbar, you can open a window with feature attributes, which is faster than editing in the attribute table and allow to easily update several selected features at once with the same value.

Then, I would write the value (0 to 9) in a field, and then join a look up table with the description of this value. Alternatively, you can create a [coded value domain](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/creating-new-attribute-domains-creating-a-new-code.htm) and select the appropriate values from a drop down list.

Comment: can you expand more what you mean by "I would store the value (1 to 9) in a field"?

Comment: Thank's for you answer! Everything is much easier! I described the details in the formulation of the question! I know about coded value domain but I need slightly different functionality

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @radouxju that the Attribute Window of Editor toolbar is the easiest when calculating features. Please notice the 3 dots at the end of the Text box for data entry. This will open a Menu of available values, you can choose one, no typing is required, except when a new value is needed.


[image]

Comment: You should edit your original answer with updated information instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: I know about these 3 dots and attribute window! But, believe me, it is still slowly when you need manually (without the automatic calculated) input data from 0 to 9 to 10,000 polygons per day! I wrote that for MapInfo exists this functionality as a hotkeys and it works very quickly and efficiently! So I want to realize this functionality for ArcMap! I would be very grateful for your help in this!